# Items order after drag and drop swap

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, drag-and-drop

I am doing a project where images in a 3×3 grid are re-arranged by drag and drop.
When an image is dragged and dropped over another, they **swap positions** and I have got that part working, but I also need a line of text at the bottom showing how the images have been re-ordered. So if I swap the items 1 and 5 the text would no longer read: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 but instead it should look like: 5,2,3,4,1,6,7,8,9.

I am really struggling with how to print the new numbers order after the items swap. Here is how it looks (the colors of the boxes were chosen randomly and have no importance):

[image: Image re-ordering]

This is my code:

```js
//IMAGE ORDER

let order = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

function showOrder(order) {
  document.getElementById('order').textContent = "Order: " + order.toString();
}

showOrder(order);

//DRAG AND DROP SWAP

var draggedImage = null;
var items;

function dragStart(e) {
  draggedImage = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  e.dataTransfer.setData("item", this.innerHTML);
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  return false;
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add("dragover");
}

function dragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove("dragover");
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (draggedImage != this) {
    draggedImage.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    draggedImage.setAttribute("data-item", this.innerHTML);

    let replacedImage = e.dataTransfer.getData("item");
    this.innerHTML = replacedImage;
    this.setAttribute("data-item", replacedImage);
  }
  return false;
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove("dragover");
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  items = document.querySelectorAll(".container .image");

  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
    item.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter);
    item.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
    item.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave);
    item.addEventListener("drop", drop);
    item.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 330px;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff5d7;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}

.order {
  width: 330px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="1"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 1.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="2"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 2.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="3"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 3.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="4"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 4.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="5"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 5.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="6"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 6.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="7"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 7.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="8"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 8.png" width="100px"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="9"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 9.png" width="100px"></div>
</div>

<div id="order"></div>
```

I have tried finding a way to indentify the position of the two images in the grid and then swapping those numbers in an array, when an image is dropped but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Would be easier to share some code so that one trying to help you has some starting point. Images are welcome for context, but you should also [edit] to create a [mcve]. please read [ask].

Comment: Updated the answer with a really cool solution, don't forget to upvote (the arrow up), thanks!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan check my latest solution in the answer. a reactive one with Proxy, seems like you wanted it to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the IDs to your draggable content () and update the order box on the drop.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container .image').forEach(div => {
  div.querySelector('img').dataset.id = div.id;
});

const updateOrder = () => {
  document.getElementById('order').textContent = 'Order: ' + 
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.container .image img')].map(img => img.dataset.id).join(', ');
};

updateOrder();

//DRAG AND DROP SWAP

var draggedImage = null;
var items;

function dragStart(e) {
    draggedImage = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed="move";
    e.dataTransfer.setData("item", this.innerHTML); 
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    return false;
}

function dragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add("dragover"); 
}

function dragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove("dragover"); 
}

function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (draggedImage != this) {
        draggedImage.innerHTML = this.innerHTML; 
        draggedImage.setAttribute("data-item", this.innerHTML);

        let replacedImage = e.dataTransfer.getData("item"); 
        this.innerHTML = replacedImage;
        this.setAttribute("data-item", replacedImage);
        updateOrder();
        }
        return false;
}

function dragEnd(e) {
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.classList.remove("dragover"); 
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    items = document.querySelectorAll(".container .image");

    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
        item.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter);
        item.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
        item.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave);
        item.addEventListener("drop", drop);
        item.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
      .container {
          width: 330px;
          height: 330px;
          background-color: lightgrey;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .image {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #fff5d7;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: move;
      }
      .order {
        width: 330px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size:x-large;
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Image re-ordering</h1>  
        <h2>Drag and drop to swap images</h2>
        <div class="container">
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="1"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 1.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="2"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 2.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="3"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 3.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="4"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 4.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="5"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 5.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="6"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 6.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="7"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 7.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="8"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 8.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="9"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 9.png" width="100px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="order" id="order"></div>
    <script src="gasflasker test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But a better approach would be to move the whole boxes:

```js
const $container = document.querySelector('.container');

const updateOrder = () => {
  document.getElementById('order').textContent = 'Order: ' + 
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.container .image')].map(img => img.id).join(', ');
};

updateOrder();

//DRAG AND DROP SWAP

var draggedImage = null;
var items;

function dragStart(e) {
    draggedImage = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed="move";
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    return false;
}

function dragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add("dragover"); 
}

function dragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove("dragover"); 
}

function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (draggedImage != this) {
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        $container.insertBefore(span, draggedImage);
        $container.insertBefore(draggedImage, this.nextSibling);
        $container.insertBefore(this, span);
        span.remove();
        updateOrder();
    }
}

function dragEnd(e) {
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.classList.remove("dragover"); 
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    items = document.querySelectorAll(".container .image");

    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
        item.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter);
        item.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
        item.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave);
        item.addEventListener("drop", drop);
        item.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
      .container {
          width: 330px;
          height: 330px;
          background-color: lightgrey;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .image {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #fff5d7;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: move;
      }
      .order {
        width: 330px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size:x-large;
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Image re-ordering</h1>  
        <h2>Drag and drop to swap images</h2>
        <div class="container">
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="1"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 1.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="2"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 2.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="3"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 3.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="4"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 4.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="5"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 5.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="6"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 6.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="7"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 7.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="8"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 8.png" width="100px"></div>
          <div draggable="true" class="image" id="9"><img src="Dummy billeder/nummer 9.png" width="100px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="order" id="order"></div>
    <script src="gasflasker test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to go really cool, here's a reactive approach without manipulating DOM manually. So you create an array from the images' IDs and manipulate it through `Proxy`. Sort the images in DOM on the array's changes. That way any additional functionality can be implemented easily, like a reset button:

```
<button onclick="ids.sort((a,b)=>a-b)">Reset</button>
```

```js
const $container = document.querySelector('.container');

let updatePromise;

const ids = new Proxy([], {
  set(target, prop, val){
    // postpone the update with a microtask
    updatePromise ??= Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      updatePromise = null;
      document.getElementById('order').textContent = 'Order: ' + 
    target.join(', ');
      target.forEach(id => {
        $container.appendChild(document.getElementById(id));
      });
    });
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, val);
  }
});

ids.push(...[...document.querySelectorAll('.container .image')].map(img => img.id));

let draggedImageId;

const events = {
  dragstart: e => {
    draggedImageId = e.target.id;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  },
  dragover: e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";  
  },
  dragenter: e => {
    const $image = e.target.closest('.image');
    $image?.id === draggedImageId || $image?.classList.add("dragover");
  },
  dragleave: e => e.target.classList.remove("dragover"),
  dragend: e => e.target.classList.remove("dragover"),
  drop: e => {
    if (e.target.id && draggedImageId !== e.target.id) {
        $container.querySelector('.dragover')?.classList.remove('dragover');
        const [from, to] = [ids.indexOf(draggedImageId), ids.indexOf(e.target.id)];
        [ids[from], ids[to]] = [ids[to], ids[from]];
    }
  }
};

for(const name in events){
  $container.addEventListener(name, events[name]);
}
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.container {
  width: 162px;
  height: 164px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius:3px;
}
.image.dragover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff5d7;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: move;
  border-radius:2px;
}
.order {
  width: 220px;
  height: 30;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="1">1</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="2">2</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="3">3</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="4">4</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="5">5</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="6">6</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="7">7</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="8">8</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="image" id="9">9</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="order" id="order"></div>
<button onclick="ids.sort((a,b)=>a-b)">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan have you seen the last? looks really cool... with Proxy

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan appreciate that)

Comment: Yes, interesting idea. But again, you're iterating again the IDs array to recreate the entire content, instead of just swapping the two DIVs - nice effort nevertheless.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, could be optimized, but 9 elements are fast to sort. from a pure standpoint it's not recreating rather moving existing nodes inside the container imho. anyway worked ok in my experience.

Comment: Added my 2¢ in an additional answer below

Comment: Very nice solutions! Thank you so much for taking the time. As a beginner I definitely have some learning to do, before I understand your solutions fully.

Comment: @AsmusMortensen you are welcome, the last one is my masterpiece, see how it's easy just to do anything with the boxes, you can easily sort the array and the boxes will be sorted automatically (the reset button). it's a very modern solution compared to manipulating DOM manually

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler and cleaner example/suggestion in where:

- Store index in `data` atrribute
- Retrieve the indexes of the dragged and target drop elements
- Swap the elements in the DOM
- Update the array given those two indexes
- Print the *order* array
- Use delegated events (assigned on the wrapper `.grid` element)

```js
const elGrid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const elOrder = document.querySelector("#order");
const order = [...elGrid.children].map(el => el.dataset.index);
let elDrag;

const showOrder = () => elOrder.textContent = `Order: ${order}`;

const events = {
  dragstart() { elDrag = this; },
  dragover(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); },
  drop() {
    if (elDrag === this) return;
    const ia = [...elGrid.children].indexOf(elDrag);
    const ib = [...elGrid.children].indexOf(this);
    elDrag.replaceWith(this.cloneNode(true));
    this.replaceWith(elDrag);
    [order[ia], order[ib]] = [order[ib], order[ia]];
    showOrder();
  }
};

[...elGrid.children].forEach((el, i) => el.draggable = true);
["dragstart", "dragover", "drop"].forEach(evName => {
  elGrid.addEventListener(evName, (ev) => {
    const elItem = ev.target.closest(".item");
    if (!elItem) return; 
    events[evName].call(elItem, ev);
  });
});
showOrder();
```

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  gap: 0.3rem;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: #fffac2;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item" data-index="1"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/0bf/fff?text=1" alt="1"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="2"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/0fb/fff?text=2" alt="2"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="3"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/bf0/fff?text=3" alt="3"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="4"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/b0f/fff?text=4" alt="4"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="5"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/fb0/fff?text=5" alt="5"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="6"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/f0b/fff?text=6" alt="6"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="7"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/8f0/fff?text=7" alt="7"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="8"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/f80/fff?text=8" alt="8"></div>
  <div class="item" data-index="9"><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40/08f/fff?text=9" alt="9"></div>
</div>

<div id="order"></div>
```

Comment: I actually thought of doing it something like this initially, but soon realized I didn't have the knowledge. But your answers is very neat! Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: @AsmusMortensen you're very welcome. One day you can always revise your old questions and I'm sure this answer code will look really familiar and understandable :)